# a new page, nested form using devise's registration path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to build a nested form in a custom page using devise.

The error that comes out is: undefined method `build_profile' for nil:NilClass

```
   <%= form_for("user", :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'E-mail Address' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => 'Password Confirmation' %>

      <% @user.build_profile %>

      <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>

      <%= profile_form.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Name' %>
      <%= profile_form.text_field :address, :placeholder => 'Address' %>
      <%= profile_form.phone_field :phone, :placeholder => 'Phone (example: 0193284647)' %>

     <% end %>

     <p><%= f.submit "Sign up", :class=>'btn btn-primary' %> </p>
    <% end %>
```

Edit (Extra information):

should i add @user = @user.build_profile by creating a users_controller.rb instead?

Would it cause problems with devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you have to do

```
@user = @user.build_profile
```

in `registrations_controller.rb` . And,mention the customize controller in `routes.rb` in `devise` method.

You should so something like

```
 class Registrations < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user = @user.build_profile
    super 
  end
 end
```